# Calculating index in a subdivided interval?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, intervals

Consider an interval of values `[x, y]` equally subdivided in `n` samples in the following way:
[image: subdivision]

`y` can be greater, equal or less than `x`. 
Now, we pick up a value `z` between `x` and `y`.

**Question:** what is the formula to compute the index `i` of `z` ? (if `x = y`, then the formula should return `0` or `n-1`) (I repeat: `y` can be greater, equal or less than `x`.)

For example: if `x = - 5`, `y = -10` and `n = 5`, then for `z = -7.5`, `i = 2` (if `z = -7`, `i = 2` but if `z = -8`, `i = 3`).

Comment: Do you know in advance the value of x and y ?

Comment: How would you do it on paper? Try it for a few different `[x,y]`, `n` and `z`. Abstract your solutions and you'll have the algorithm.

Comment: @jrok [-5 ->0] [-6 ->1] [-7 ->2] [-8 ->3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the length of the interval as:

```
  len = y - x
```

Then you can compute the increase per a single element

```
  increase = len / n;
```

And now you have `i = (z - x) / increase`. In short you compute how much does the value increase per a single element and than you compute how many times this increase is needed to get from `x` to `z`.

EDIT: if you really require the solution in `C++` take care to do all the calculations in double. Also please note the value of i should be an integer rounded down.

Answer (score 0):

Answer logic(IN java):

> i = Math.abs(Math.ceil(z - Math.min(x,y)));

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x>y) high = x low = y

else high = y low = x

if(y>=x)
    i = ceil((z-low+1)/(high-low+1)*n)-1

else i = ceil((high-z+1)/(high-low+1)*n)-1
```